# open url through header in php

Tags: php

I have a .php file in which i have a added a simple code:

```
<?php
header("Location:http//www.google.com");
?>
```

when i run this code, then instead of opening google.com it opens a download file, which is the same as my php file.

Comment: what is this "simple code" you speak of?

Comment: Please be more clear. Don't understand what your question.

Comment: Congratulations! Is that what you intended it to do? Why are you telling us?

Answer (score 5):

You have to make sure your server is setup to parse php files.

Something like this in apache:

`AddHandler php5 .php .php5`

**edit**

You would add this in the apache configuration file. `httpd.conf`

Take a look at this [article](http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/install-php-5-apache-windows.shtml). It walks you step by step on how to do this. I am assuming you are using windows.

Answer (score 3):

You need a space after `Location:` for the redirect to work properly. Also, make sure you have the colon after `http`.

Try

```
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: A space after the colon is not required. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2

Comment: @Gumbo While the spec may say that, as we know one can't trust that all browsers and proxy servers reliably implement the spec. I don't recall the details at the moment, but I have had issues with that in the past.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [install/enable](http://php.net/manual/en/install.php) you server's php module, or if you are in windows, download [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php) and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you meant

```
<?php header("Location: http://www.google.com"); ?>
```

?

Comment: yea i m doing the same but its not opening the google page
rather a downloading link

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on a server? If not, download [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) and put your PHP file in the htdocs folder. Then click xampp_start.exe in the main folder. Then go to localhost/youphpfile.php in your web browser.